# How can i extract value of properties from anonymous class?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

When i declare

```
object o = new { name = "Bruce",Age=21 };
Console.WriteLine("name={0},age={1}",???,??? );
```

Now how can i print value of name and age?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dont assign to an object variable, use var:

```
var o = new { name = "Bruce", Age = 21 };
Console.WriteLine( "name={0},age={1}, o.name, o.Age );
```

Comment: @James: Anonymous types in C# only exist beginning in v 3.0 of the language. So to use them you need implicitly typed variables, which is one of the reasons var was introduced.

Comment: ofcourse I am using C# 3.0 only,so it would be helpful,Thanks to Bushkin.

Answer (score 3):

While not accessing the properties directly (see [LBushkin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572722/how-can-i-extract-value-of-properties-from-anonymous-class/1572742#1572742)'s answer). ToString() is overloaded to list the content of all of the properties

```
var o = new { name = "Bruce", Age = 21 };
Console.WriteLine(o);// { name = Bruce, Age = 21 }
```